# If $0 \le a \le 1$, then show that $xa + (1-a)y$ will always lie between $x$ and $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $0 \le a \le 1$, then show that $xa + (1-a)y$ will always lie between $x$ and $y$.

I am sorry if this may seem like elementary question. I have tried many examples and they all seem to work. Still I am not able to prove this.

Can any one prove(or point me in some direction) this both intuitively and formally.

Comment: actually it is between $y$ and $x$ as you wrote it.  Just write $z=xa+(1-a)y=y + a(x-y)$ and it will be clear why it is like that.

Comment: By proving this, How can you prove that *e* will be on line *pq*. While trying many examples I just happened to observe that it generalizes to all and then I asked this question. I then realized that it is now a mathematical question and thus I posted here.

Comment: If we consider $x,y$ as data, then the value $xa + (1-a)y$ for $a \in [0,1]$ corresponds to a weighted average of this data. Averages are always in between data.

Comment: @AbhinavGarg, my mistake.  They're not the same.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @D.W. Its Ok. You were only performing your duty. Mistakes Happen. We are only humans. So now can you please remove the duplicate tag? It might hinder the question's visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $y\le x$
$$\text{Let  }0\le a \le 1.$$
$$\implies 0\le a(x-y) \le x-y$$
$$\implies y\le y+ a(x-y) \le y+x-y$$
$$\implies y\le ax+(1-a)y \le x$$

If $x\lt y$, the same argument applies by setting $b=1-a$, thus
$$x\le by +(1-b)x\lt y$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\;x<y\;$ :

$$\begin{align*}&ax+(1-a)y\le a\color{red}y+(1-a)y=y\\{}\\
{}\\&ax+(1-a)y\ge ax+(1-a)\color{blue}x=x\end{align*}$$

Thus, from the both lines above

$$x\le ax+(1-a)y\le y$$

Comment: Please do not edit my answer without my permission, unless it is a gramatical mistake or the like. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Sorry about the edits. I edited the wrong answer in error. oops!

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Notice you have a continuous monotone function with $f(0) = y$ and $f(1)=x$...

Comment: This question is marked pre-calculus though.

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy what do you need calculus for? $f$ is linear in $a$ and hence is monotone, no derivatives necessary.

Comment: @gt6989b I think Kennedy may have meant that you need *continuity* and the intermediate value theorem, which is usually taught in calculus, not in pre-calculus.

Comment: @Joanpemo with effort you can replace continuity and linearity... formally you do need the IVT for this argument, i agree...

Comment: It is particularly desirable when using (relative to the Question) advanced ideas to solve a problem, to make their presentation more of a coherent argument and less of an abrupt "hint".

Comment: I know **a little bit of elementary calculus ideas** like continuity, what do derivatives and integrals signify. If you can then please solve it using calculus. If there are any advanced ideas I can very well learn them

Answer (score 0):

It is not restrictive to assume $x\le y$. Consider
$$
xa+(1-a)y=xa+x(1-a)-x(1-a)+(1-a)y=
x+(1-a)(y-x)
$$
and conclude $xa+(1-a)y\ge x$.

Can you do similarly for getting $xa+(1-a)y\le y$?

Comment: should it not be $>=y$ and $<=x$ ?

Comment: @GCab Why? If I assume $x\le y$, I want $x\le xa+(1-a)y\le y$, don't I?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I overlooked the hypothesis you made at the beginning